# lapply for a function that requires indexing

Tags: r, indexing, apply

I'm trying to find the log return along a vector of prices but not sure how to call an index inside a function for use in an apply function.

Here's what I'm using now:

```
set.seed(456)
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:20, col1 = round( runif(20) * 100 ,0))
df1[,'logDiff'] <- NA

for(i in 2:20){
df1[i,'logDiff'] <- log(df1[i,'col1'] / df1[i-1,'col1'])
}
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I have a bunch of columns to do this for and would like to use something like this:

```
colsToUse <- c('co1l','col2','col3')
lagLogDf <- as.data.frame(lapply(df1[,colsToUse], lagLogFunction(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

As you want the difference between consecutive values of a vector, you can use the `diff` function:

```
df1$logDiff = c(NA, diff(log(df1$col)))
```

Alternatively (for instance, if your operation were more complicated than cumulative differences), you could use `head` and `tail` to get the vector missing the first element and missing the last element, and work with them in a vectorized way:

```
df1$logDiff = c(NA, log(tail(df1$col1, -1) / head(df1$col1, -1)))
```